# brew upgrade 'python 3.6.5 already installed` but python version is 3.6.4

Tags: python, installation, homebrew, failed-installation

`brew upgrade` hint that 'python 3.6.5 already installed`

```
$ brew upgrade python
Updated 2 taps (homebrew/core, caskroom/cask).
==> Updated Formulae
aria2              cake               debianutils        grpc               sops               you-get
aws-sdk-cpp        dbxml              fdroidserver       pilosa             xqilla

Error: python 3.6.5 already installed
```

However,

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.
(ll_env)
```

How to upgrade a specified python running in an environment?

Comment: Do you mean you are running Python in a virtualenv?

Comment: What is the result of `/usr/bin/python --version` ?

Comment: python is /Users/me/Desktop/Django/learning_log/ll_env/bin/python @Rafael

Comment: $ type -a python
python is /Users/me/Desktop/Django/learning_log/ll_env/bin/python
python is /Users/me/anaconda3/bin/python
python is /usr/bin/python

Comment: Seems relevant: https://xkcd.com/1987/

Comment: I want to upgrade the version in the environment.

Comment: Many people report a smoother Python experience with Anaconda instead of brew.

Comment: `conda update python` ty @OliverCharlesworth